# Makefile - recompile

Tags: makefile

My makefile always recompiles everything in directory if one header is changed. It's not a problem now but since I'm adding more to my program this is becoming and issue. I don't want to wait for a whole recompile if I add a new variable to a header of a separate class object.
Here is my makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CPPFLAGS = -I -lm -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

OBJ = CR_Main.o CarRental.o CR_Button.o CR_LoginMenu.o CR_TextBox.o CR_UserCreation.o CR_CheckBox.o

DEPS = CarRental.hpp CR_Button.hpp CR_LoginMenu.hpp CR_TextBox.hpp CR_UserCreation.hpp CR_CheckBox.hpp

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS)

CRC.exe: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CPPFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    del *.o *.exe
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I was wondering why is it compiling everything in my directory if only 1 out 6 .hpp files are modified on one line? Is something wrong with my makefile or is that how it is?

Comment: Well, you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Silly me! I was wondering why is it compiling everything in my directory if only 1 out 6 .hpp files are modified on one line? Is something wrong with my makefile or is that how it is?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're confused.  The rule `%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)` tells `make` that all `.o` files depend on any of the headers listed in `$(DEPS)`.  So if any of those headers change all object files will be rebuilt.

Comment: Thank you! I dont fully understand makefile rules yet. Is there any way i can specify, in makefile, which .cpp file depends on which header?

Comment: Sure.  If the `foo.c` file includes `foo.h`, you can write `foo.o: foo.h` which tells make that if the `foo.h` file is newer than `foo.o`, then it should rebuild `foo.o`.  If it depends on both `foo.h` and `bar.h`, you can write `foo.o: foo.h bar.h`.  Etc.  There are also some facilities that can be used to automatically generate these dependencies so you don't have to maintain them by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is it compiling everything in my directory if only 1 out 6 .hpp files are modified on one line? Is something wrong with my makefile or is that how it is?

"Wrong" might be too strong a word, but yes, the behavior you describe is a consequence of how your makefile is written.

This rule ...

```
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS)
```

... says, roughly, that you can build `.o` files from corresponding `.cpp` files plus all the files named in variable `DEPS`.  This implies that if that's the rule `make` selects for building a given `.o` file, and *any* of those prerequisites is newer than the target, then the target is out of date and needs to be rebuilt.  You have named all your headers in `DEPS` and you have not provided any other rules for building `.o` files, so yes, if any of your headers changes, all of the `.o` files will be rebuilt.

The most simple-minded alternative would be to write a separate rule for each `.o`, naming the prerequisites of that file only.  That is, the corresponding `.cpp` file and whichever headers it `#include`s, directly or indirectly.

But you can save yourself a little typing by instead removing the `$(DEPS)` part from your existing rule, and adding an additional rule for each `.o` that does not have a recipe but names all the header prerequisites for that file.

Or if, as it appears, you have consistent relationships between source file names and header names, you might do something like this:

```
CXX = g++
CPPFLAGS = -I.
LIBS = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window -lsfml-system  -lm

MAIN_OBJ = CR_Main.o 
MODULE_OBJS = CarRental.o CR_Button.o CR_LoginMenu.o CR_TextBox.o CR_UserCreation.o CR_CheckBox.o

$(MAIN_OBJ): CR_Main.cpp $(MODULE_OBJS:.o=.h)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.cpp %.h
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

CRC.exe: $(MAIN_OBJ) $(MODULE_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

# Extra dependencies (guesses for the sake of example):
CarRental.o CR_LoginMenu.o CR_UserCreation.o: CR_TextBox.h CR_CheckBox.h
# No recipe here

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    del $(MAIN_OBJ) $(MODULE_OBJS) CRC.exe
```

Ultimately, though, what you would really like to do is generate all the header dependencies automatically.  That makes the project much easier to maintain once you get it initially set up.  You can find lots of information about that on the web, some of it [in the GNU `make` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html).

Comment: In general I consider it a bad idea to add a `%.h` to a pattern rule.  This means that if you try to compile a `.c` file and it _doesn't_ have a header, this rule will not match.  That can be pretty confusing.  You should only use this if you have a coding standard that requires a `.h` for EVERY source file, regardless of whether it's really needed or not.  Also note this only recompiles source if their _own_ header changes; more interesting is recompiling when some other header changes.  If you don't want to manage that by hand, some compilers can help.

Comment: I agree with all of that @MadScientist, and I think at least most of it is already addressed by this answer, between prose and code.